# Testing my Google App Engine Flex Locally (without deploying)

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to test my wordpress install which I have set up already and deployed. I have to debug, so waiting 10-15 mins for it to deploy to test one thing isn't going to work.

All they mention in their docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally

**Running locally**

"To test your application's functionality before deploying, run your application in your local environment with the development tools that you usually use."

That's it. How can I actually serve my wordpress application? My tools I "usually use" are xampp...very confused.

Can someone help me run my flex env locally to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart#run_hello_world_on_your_local_machine) for the initial tests for your PHP application. You would have to install `composer` on your shell for it, if you haven't done it already.

Then, for the WordPress application, follow the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible#creating_and_configuring_a_cloud_sql_second_generation_instance) to test the Cloud SQL instance that is associated to the app. There is also the [possibility](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible#updating_wordpress_plugins_and_themes) to test all the updates you want to apply to the WordPress side. Skip the deploying part until you confirm all your changes work for you, so that you don't have to wait all that time for a deployment.

Comment: I guess that was pretty easy :P. Was able to serve it locally and use the gcloud proxy. thanks!